# Servir un conjunto de ficheros a usuarios logueados previamente

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, login, backend

Quiero servir una página de html que tiene asociado un fichero de estilo css y un fichero js. El fichero js importa funciones de otros ficheros js.
Asumo que para servir mi página de html tengo que servir además el resto de ficheros a los que hace referencia, el de estilo y los diferentes ficheros js.
la única opción que de momento he visto googleando para servir una carpeta entera de ficheros en node-express es `app.use('/static', express.static('public'));`
Pero parece ser una opción utilizada para servir contenidos que están accesibles de forma pública.   Lo que estoy buscando es servir conjuntos de ficheros a usuarios previamente logueados. Esto es porque estoy haciendo un juego-simulador, con su propia librería de funciones escritas en js,  que solo quiero que esté accesible a los usuarios que previamente se han logueado.
Este es mi entry point en el backend, `index.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const session = require("express-session");
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const passport = require("passport");

//Initializations
const app = express();
require("./database");

//Setting
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.engine(
  ".hbs",
  exphbs.engine({
    defaultLayout: "main",
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get("views"), "layouts"),
    partialsDir: [
      path.join(app.get("views"), "partials"),
      path.join(app.get("views"), "menu"),
      path.join(app.get("views"), "playground"),
    ],
    extname: ".hbs",
  })
);
app.set("view engine", ".hbs");

//Middlewares
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "mysecretapp",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require("./config/passport")(passport);
app.use(flash());
//Glbal Variables
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash("success_msg");
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash("error_msg");
  res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
  next();
});
//Routes
app.use(require("./routes/index"));
app.use(require("./routes/simulations"));
app.use(require("./routes/users"));

//Static Files
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
//app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "test")));
//app.use('/playground',express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../frontend")));
//app.use(express.static("test"));
//app.use('/test', express.static('public'));

//Server is listenning
app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log("Server on port", app.get("port"));
});

module.exports = app;
```

Luego tengo en la carpeta "routes" uno fichero que se llama `simulations.js` donde tengo las rutas relativas a mi juego-simulador:

```
const router = require("express").Router();

const Game = require("../models/Game");
const { isAuthenticated } = require("../helpers/auth");
let app = require("./index");
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");



router.post(
  "/simulations/new-simulation",
  isAuthenticated,
  async (req, res) => {
    req.flash("success_msg", "New stage created for a new simulation");
    res.redirect("/playground/new-simulation");
  }
);


router.get("/menu", isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  res.render("menu/main-menu");
});


router.get("/playground/new-simulation", isAuthenticated, async (req, res) => {
  app.use("/playground", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../frontend")));
  res.redirect("index-script.html");
});



module.exports = router;
```

El problema lo tengo aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no sé que está ocurriendo, sí es que no se están sirviendo el conjunto de ficheros o es que no hay una ruta definida en mi carpeta de routes para "/playground/index-script.html"

**Formato de la respuesta:**
Como respuesta se admite al menos una de los dos posibles formatos de respuestas descritas a continuación:

- Formato de respuesta A: **¿Cómo servir un conjunto de ficheros a un usuario que previamente se ha logueado?** (es decir un conjunto de ficheros al que no pueden acceder alguien que no se haya registrado previamente) La pregunta es cerrada, seguramente existan varias formas de hacer esto. **Solo se pide como respuesta mencionar al menos una forma**.
  Con esta pregunta no se pretende generar un debate sobre cuál es la mejor manera.
- Formato de respuesta B: **¿Cuál es la solución a mi problema concreto?**. En este post estoy proponiendo una solución pero está incompleta, si alguien desea señalar la causa de mi problema técnico y propone al menos una solución, se admitirá esta información como respuesta a la pregunta. También se admitirá como respuesta una explicación que justifique un mal planteamiento de la solución que estoy tratando de desarrollar en este post si ese fuera el caso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He comprobado que el procedimiento descrito es correcto. El único problema estaba en mi fichero de `simulations.js`, en la línea:

```
app.use("/playground", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../frontend")));
```

La ruta estaba mal escrita, debía de ponerla así:

```
app.use("/playground", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../frontend")));
```